# When would $\underline{\nabla} \cdot \underline{F} = 0$?

Tags: vector-analysis, index-notation

I see that
$$\underline{\nabla} \cdot \underline{F} = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_3} = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_i}$$
But what would be the case for this to be zero?

Comment: This is an underdetermined partial differential equation there are many solutions to it (see the answer of Arthur)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a vector field is called divergenceless. A physical example from fluid dynamics would involve the velocity field of the fluid. This is divergenceless if there are no sources and sinks (assuming an [incompressible fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_flow)).

An important theorem for divergenceless is the Gauss theorem which in this context implies that
$$\int_S \vec{F}\cdot \vec{n} \,dS =0$$
with $S$ an arbitrary closed surface and $\vec{n}$ the normal to it.

An trivial example would be $$\vec{F} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @M.Turner: that is a different question (I suggest to start a new one). The solution to this problem involves Gauss' theorem and a [vector identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) -- I would guess the relevant one is the divergence version of the product of a scalar and a vector.

Comment: Okay thank you. @Fabian

Answer (score 2):

For continuously differentiable $F$ defined on *all* of $\Bbb R^3$, the divergence of $F$ is zero exactly when $F$ is the curl of some other vector field $G$.